# How to only allow certian roles ot use this command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to only allow people with the Staff role to run this command.
Basically what the command does, is allowing a bot to DM users
the command is `<prefix>send @RandomUserName <message>`

I am trying to prevent random users from abusing this command to flood other players DMs.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Staff')) return;
    if (command === 'send'){
        function getUserFromMention(mention) {
            if (!mention) return;
            if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
                mention = mention.slice(2, -1);
                if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
                    mention = mention.slice(1);
                }
                return mention;
            }
        }
        const user = getUserFromMention(args[0])
        let MessageDM = args[1]
        client.users.cache.get(user).send(MessageDM);
    }
    // ...
});
```

Comment: You're missing a `!`: `if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Staff')) return;` - the way you have it disallows usage when the staff role is present. Also, having a function inside an `if` is never a good idea.

Comment: umm where do i put the cahe role name

Comment: ooh wait give ma a sec let me do a quick test on my code

Comment: Okay it works i get what you mean. Also where should i put the functions instedt?

Comment: Somewhere in the upper scope. Ill post it as answer if that did indeed solve your problem

Comment: yeah it solved it thanks man

Comment: wait have a 2nd question (Quick one) how do i add a  message.channel.send("") saying the message has been successfully delivered like wich part of the code to put it in

Comment: after `client.users.cache.get(user).send(MessageDM);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a negation (`!`) in your role-check. Your current `if` only evaluates to true, when the role is present. But you want to `return` if the role is *not* present.

Change your line

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Staff')) return;
```

to

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Staff')) return;
```

---

Also, as I mentioned in my comment, putting a `function` inside an `if` is never a good idea. I'd just put it into the upper scope:

```js
function getUserFromMention(mention) {
    if (!mention) return;
    if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
        mention = mention.slice(2, -1);
        if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
            mention = mention.slice(1);
        }
        return mention;
    }
}

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Staff')) return;
    if (command === 'send'){
        const user = getUserFromMention(args[0]);
        let MessageDM = args[1];
        client.users.cache.get(user).send(MessageDM);
    }
    // ...
});
```